# Plane won't merge into one vertex

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, vertices

I am in the middle of modelling an AK-47, and I'm doing each of the parts separately.

I trace the reference image by adding in a plane, going into *Edit Mode*, and tapping <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> and then clicking *Merge at Center*, but this is the third plane I'm using and its not working.

I've tried different merge options to no avail, and not only that, when I merge the plane, I can't see or move the one vertex, though it shows up in the object menu still.

[image]

https://media.giphy.com/media/3oFzlWU9144SjFQjaU/giphy.gif

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish. But, you can SHIFT + "A" Add a Single Vert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the vertex use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad Period</kbd>.

[image]

That will zoom the view to the selected vertex.

Instead of adding a plane just to get rid of all of the vertices, add a single vertex object. Then in edit mode you can make connected edges by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and left clicking.

[image]

Comment: nevermind, downloaded the addon. thanks a ton cegaton